# Transform column in table by its values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1:

```
id     date          type         value
1   2020-10-05      open           2
1   2020-10-05      download       6
1   2020-10-05      update         15
2   2020-10-05      open           2
2   2020-10-05      download       6
2   2020-10-06      open           11
3   2020-10-05      open           8
3   2020-10-05      close          16
```

I need to transform column "value". As you see for each group by columns "id" and "date" there are "type" open. For each group, i want to divide values by its "open" value (besides of open itself). How could i do that> Desired result is:

```
id     date          type         value
1   2020-10-05      open           2     # no change cause its open
1   2020-10-05      download       3     #cause 6/2 = 3
1   2020-10-05      update         7.5   #cause 15/2 = 7.5
2   2020-10-05      open           2     # no change cause its open
2   2020-10-05      download       3     #cause 6/2 = 3
2   2020-10-06      open           11    # no change cause its open
3   2020-10-05      open           8     # no change cause its open
3   2020-10-05      close          2     #cause 16/8 = 2
```

I tried this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  mutate(value_new = value / value[type == "open"],
         value_new = if_else(type == "open", value, value_new))
```

But with this method count_new roundsand i get this (third row is 7, not 7.5):

```
id     date          type         value
1   2020-10-05      open           2     # no change cause its open
1   2020-10-05      download       3     #cause 6/2 = 3
1   2020-10-05      update         7     #cause 15/2 = 7.5
2   2020-10-05      open           2     # no change cause its open
2   2020-10-05      download       3     #cause 6/2 = 3
2   2020-10-06      open           11    # no change cause its open
3   2020-10-05      open           8     # no change cause its open
3   2020-10-05      close          2     #cause 16/8 = 2
```

How to prevent it from rounding?

Comment: For me it does exactly what you like to have, third row is 7.5, not 7, it does not round. Also, could you print your data with `dput()` or the `regrex` package to have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new_value = value/value[match('open', type)], 
                new_value = ifelse(type == 'open', value, new_value))

#     id date       type     value new_value
#  <int> <chr>      <chr>    <int>     <dbl>
#1     1 2020-10-05 open         2       2  
#2     1 2020-10-05 download     6       3  
#3     1 2020-10-05 update      15       7.5
#4     2 2020-10-05 open         2       2  
#5     2 2020-10-05 download     6       3  
#6     2 2020-10-06 open        11      11  
#7     3 2020-10-05 open         8       8  
#8     3 2020-10-05 close       16       2
```

---

your attempt would work if you change `value` to numeric.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  mutate(value_new = value / value[type == "open"],
         value_new = if_else(type == "open", as.numeric(value), value_new))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id, date) %>% 
   mutate(value = case_when(type == 'open' ~ value, TRUE ~ value/value[type == 'open']))

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   id, date [4]
     id date       type     value
  <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 2020-10-05 open       2  
2     1 2020-10-05 download   3  
3     1 2020-10-05 update     7.5
4     2 2020-10-05 open       2  
5     2 2020-10-05 download   3  
6     2 2020-10-06 open      11  
7     3 2020-10-05 open       8  
8     3 2020-10-05 close      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reshaping:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = type,values_from=value) %>%
  mutate(across(download:close,~./open)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,date)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  rename(type=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id date       name      type
  <int> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
1     1 2020-10-05 open       2  
2     1 2020-10-05 download   3  
3     1 2020-10-05 update     7.5
4     2 2020-10-05 open       2  
5     2 2020-10-05 download   3  
6     2 2020-10-06 open      11  
7     3 2020-10-05 open       8  
8     3 2020-10-05 close      2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), date = c("2020-10-05", 
"2020-10-05", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-05", "2020-10-06", 
"2020-10-05", "2020-10-05"), type = c("open", "download", "update", 
"open", "download", "open", "open", "close"), value = c(2L, 6L, 
15L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```